# ubuntu expectations for laptop drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, sound, video, laptop

I'm brand new to the ubuntu world. I'm trying to understand what ubuntu requires in the way of drivers (wireless, video, audio etc) when it's going to be installed on a laptop.

I noticed when I ran Ubuntu from a memory stick that I could not get data to pass thru the Ethernet port nor the wireless card. When I installed Ubuntu in a "side by side" arrangement on this same XP laptop the Ethernet port worked and the wireless card works.

So is the expectation for laptops that you have to have windows drivers already in place and Ubuntu has to be installed side by side?

If I had a blank disk-drive would I need to find and download windows drivers and install them via Ubuntu?

I'm not understanding the approach that needs to be taken regarding wireless, video and audio drivers and Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use Windows drivers when installed side by side. If fact, native linux drivers should be used in all cases you've mentioned. You also should never need to look for drivers on Ubuntu, some corner cases aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on the specific laptop. A great many drivers exist by default in the kernel for common devices. Laptop manufacturers, however, love to surprise the world, and by extension Ubuntu, with new devices for which there is only a mostly working Windows driver. In those cases, a question and answer here on this site usually solves the problem.

There are a few wireless drivers that require proprietary firmware files or drivers. Ubuntu is not truly free and open source if it includes by default those files and so the option is given to install additional drivers during install.

> So is the expectation for laptops that you have to have windows
>   drivers already in place and Ubuntu has to be installed side by side?

Not at all. I am fairly certain that your experience was anomalous. A great many of us here have no Windows install at all. In my own case, on a Lenovo T410i, I did a bare harddrive install and everything worked as expected right from the start.

I urge you to try the live USB or DVD again and if everything works as expected this time, install. If not, post a question with specific questions. If you want extra assurance, remove the Windows harddrive entirely before you start.